# How to change color of a ListBox item dynamically (using a list of class objects that are bound to it)? C# UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, listbox, uwp

I am using two ListBox elements. One is the parent (BucketListBox), which decides what is supposed to be displayed in child. Child (ObjectListBox) is in multi-select mode. Once I choose particular elements in child, I shift to another parent, the child ListBox is updated with new choices.

When the user shifts back to a previously browsed parent, he should be able to see the old choices in the child that he had selected then. I am maintaining a list of the items user selects in child. I want to use this list to change background color of those elements he had previously selected.

As of now, those elements are still selected, but not shown in UI.

Here is my XAML code for the parent:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="BucketListBox" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" SelectionChanged="BucketListBox_SelectionChanged">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Margin="10,10,10,10">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RelativePanel Grid.Row="0">
                <TextBlock x:Name="BucketNameLabel" x:Uid="NameLabel"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" x:Name="BucketNameTextBlock" RelativePanel.AlignBottomWith="BucketNameLabel" RelativePanel.RightOf="BucketNameLabel" Text="{Binding BucketName}" Margin="10,10,10,10"/>
            </RelativePanel>
            <RelativePanel Grid.Row="1">
                <TextBlock x:Name="BucketCreationDateLabel" FontSize="12" x:Uid="CreationDateLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="BucketCreationDateTextBlock" FontSize="12" RelativePanel.RightOf="BucketCreationDateLabel" RelativePanel.AlignBottomWith="BucketCreationDateLabel" Text="{Binding BucketCreationDate}" Margin="10,10,10,10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
            </RelativePanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Code for child ListBox:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="ObjectListBox" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" SelectionMode="Multiple">

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
            <DataTemplate >
                <Grid Margin="10,10,10,10">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RelativePanel Grid.Row="0">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="NameLabel" x:Uid="NameLabel" Margin="10,10,10,10" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="ObjectNameTextBlock" Text="{Binding ObjectName}" RelativePanel.RightOf="NameLabel" RelativePanel.AlignBottomWith="NameLabel" Margin="10,10,10,10" />
                    </RelativePanel>
                    <RelativePanel Grid.Row="1">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="SizeLabel" FontSize="12" x:Uid="SizeLabel"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="ObjectSize" FontSize="12" Margin="10,10,10,10" Text="{Binding Path=ObjectSize}" RelativePanel.RightOf="SizeLabel" RelativePanel.AlignBottomWith="SizeLabel"/>
                    </RelativePanel>
                    <RelativePanel Grid.Row="2">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="ObjectModificationDateLabel" FontSize="12" x:Uid="ModificationDateLabel" Margin="10,10,10,10" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="ObjectModificationDateTextBlock" FontSize="12" Text="{Binding ObjectLastModificationDate}" Margin="10,10,10,10" RelativePanel.RightOf="ObjectModificationDateLabel" RelativePanel.AlignBottomWith="ObjectModificationDateLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                    </RelativePanel>

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

And here is the code for updating ListBoxItem: (called whenever the user clicks on a new item in parent ListBox)

```
private void UpdateListBoxWithSelectedItems()
    {
        List<S3ObjectInfoHolder> currentList = (List<S3ObjectInfoHolder>)ObjectListBox.ItemsSource; //Getting the total elements being displayed in the current child list box
        foreach (S3ObjectInfoHolder entry in listOfObjectsToTransfer) //listOfObjectsToTransfer is the list of all the entries from all the parents selected so far. So the intersection of currentList with this list gives the ones that are to be colored on UI so as the user knows the items are still selected
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < currentList.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (currentList[i].ObjectName.Equals(entry.ObjectName))
                {
                    ObjectListBox.SelectedItems.Add(entry);
                    Debug.WriteLine("Selected Item:" + entry.ObjectName);
                }
            }
        }
        List<object> selectedItem = ObjectListBox.SelectedItems.ToList();
        foreach (object item in selectedItem)
        {
            ListBoxItem selectedListBoxItem = ObjectListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem((S3ObjectInfoHolder)item) as ListBoxItem;
            if(selectedListBoxItem!=null) selectedListBoxItem.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Turquoise);
        }
    }
```

**selectedListBoxItem!=null** fails, and the line is skipped.
And lastly, here is the code for the binding class:

```
class S3ObjectInfoHolder
{
    private string key;
    private string bucketName;
    private long size;
    private string isObjectAFolder;
    private string objectLastModificationDate;

    public S3ObjectInfoHolder(string key, string bucketName)
    {
        this.key = key;
        this.bucketName = bucketName;
        isObjectAFolder = isObjectAFolderOrAFile(key);
    }

    private string isObjectAFolderOrAFile(string key)
    {
        if (key[key.Length - 1] == '/')
        {
            return "is a Folder";
        }
        else
        {
            return "is a File";
        }
    }

    public string ObjectName
    {
        get
        {
            return key;
        }

        set
        {
            key = value;
        }
    }

    public long ObjectSize
    {
        get
        {
            return size;
        }

        set
        {
            size = value;
        }
    }

    public string ObjectIsFolder
    {
        get
        {
            return isObjectAFolder;
        }

        set
        {
            isObjectAFolder = value;
        }
    }

    public string BucketName
    {
        get
        {
            return bucketName;
        }

        set
        {
            bucketName = value;
        }
    }

    public string ObjectLastModificationDate
    {
        get
        {
            return objectLastModificationDate;
        }

        set
        {
            objectLastModificationDate = value;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What does "shift" mean to you? Change focus?

Comment: He clicks on a different item in parent ListBox (which basically shows Amazon S3 Buckets). When he clicks on this new bucket, the contents of that bucket are shown. Now I need to color UI dynamically so that when he comes back to this bucket where he had chosen some items in child, those again get colored.

Comment: It looks like you have code to do that already. Is something not working right?

Comment: selectedListBoxItem!=null fails, and the line is skipped. I don't know why. Am I doing something wrong there? (See the last five lines of UpdateListBoxWithSelectedItems() function)

Answer (score 1):

1. `S3ObjectInfoHolder` needs to implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged).

   ```
   public class NotificationBase : INotifyPropertyChanged {
       protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string property = null)
       {
           var handler = PropertyChanged;
           if (handler != null) 
           { 
               handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property)); 
           }
       }
   }

   public class S3ObjectInfoHolder : NotificationBase
   {
       //  ...
   ```
2. Add this property to `S3ObjectInfoHolder`

   ```
   public class S3ObjectInfoHolder : NotificationBase
   {
       //  ...

       private bool _isSelected = false;
       public bool IsSelected {
          get { return _isSelected; }
          set {
               if (_isSelected != value) {
                   _isSelected == value;
                   RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsSelected));
               }
           }
       }

       //  ...
   ```
3. Write a value converter that chooses between two brushes based on a boolean value. This can go in your codebehind, or in a separate file.

   ```
   public class BrushChooserConverter : IValueConverter
   {
       public Brush TrueBrush { get; set; }
       public Brush FalseBrush { get; set; }

       public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
           object parameter, string language)
       {
           return System.Convert.ToBoolean(value)
                       ? TrueBrush
                       : FalseBrush;
       }

       // No need to implement converting back on a one-way binding 
       public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
           object parameter, string language)
       {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
       }
   }
   ```
4. Create an instance of the value converter in the ListBox's Resources, and use the converter to set the Grid background in your data template:

   ```
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <local:BrushChooserConverter
            x:Key="SelectedItemBrushChooser"
            TrueBrush="Turquoise"
            FalseBrush="Transparent"
            />
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid 
                Background="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource SelectedItemBrushChooser}}"
                Margin="10">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <!-- ... -->
   ```
5. Set properties on the data items and let the XAML do the work. Don't mess with controls in code behind, it's always a mess because XAML controls aren't meant to be used that way. In a XAML `ListBox`, any `ListBoxItem` that isn't currently visible will be reused for another data item. This is called "virtualization"; it cuts down on the number of controls that are created.

   So when the user scrolls this thing, when an item with a colored background is scrolled out of view, that actual `ListBoxItem` control will be reused for the next item that is scrolled into view. It will still have the same background color you gave it. Will that be correct? Often not, and there is *no event you can handle to step in and correct it*. No event at all. That's because you should be using databinding anyway instead of messing with the controls directly.

   You bought yourself a hideous can of worms trying to do this in codebehind. It's worse than you know. But the databinding approach I'm showing you is much more error-proof, so it's all good.

   You should have a main viewmodel instead of doing this in codebehind; I urge you to research that.

   All a viewmodel really is, is a class that inherits from the `NotificationBase` I gave you, or from some other base class just like it. A viewmodel's properties raise notifications when they change, and it uses `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>` for any collection that might have items added or removed while it's being used as an `ItemsSource`.

   `S3ObjectInfoHolder`, with my changes, is starting to become a viewmodel. It's not the main viewmodel. It's a child viewmodel. You should add the `RaisePropertyChanged` call to every property it has. When you do that, and you use a `Binding` with that property in XAML, the `Binding` will be notified when the property's value changes, and the UI will update automatically.

   But for now, I'll just show you how to modify what you've got.

   I don't understand your code. I don't know why you're comparing names. Maybe `currentList[i]` and `entry` are the same actual object; I can't guess.

   ```
   private void UpdateListBoxWithSelectedItems()
   {
       List<S3ObjectInfoHolder> currentList = (List<S3ObjectInfoHolder>)ObjectListBox.ItemsSource; 
       foreach (S3ObjectInfoHolder entry in listOfObjectsToTransfer) {
           for (int i = 0; i < currentList.Count(); i++)
           {
               if (currentList[i].ObjectName.Equals(entry.ObjectName))
               {
                   ObjectListBox.SelectedItems.Add(entry);
                   entry.IsSelected = true;
                   Debug.WriteLine("Selected Item:" + entry.ObjectName);
               }
               else
               {
                   entry.IsSelected = false;
               }
           }
       }
   ```

   And get rid of the second loop with the container stuff.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try this out and will let you know if there are any problems! :) Will look into ViewModel. New to this! :D It's my first UWP application.

Comment: Hi, I tried using this solution. There is a problem I'm facing with your solution. DataTemplate.Triggers doesn't exist for UWP. Can you help with a work around?

Comment: What is Brushes.Transparent? Shows error! Sorry if it's trivial.

Comment: @AyushSoni What error? That's the transparent brush. I removed that initialization. It's C#6 syntax which you may not have.

Comment: 'Object' does not contain definition for 'Transparent' and no extension method 'Transparent' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found...
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That's bizarre. Did you just paste in exactly what I gave you? Do you have `using System.Windows.Media;` at the top of that file?

Comment: Nope, I have -> using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
Yes I pasted your code.

Comment: Okay, I'm retrying. Will let you know if I face any problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: <local:BrushChooserConverter 

... This line is giving error. Where should I place the converter? It says BrushChooserConverter not found in namespace ..

Comment: Is `xmlns:local=` namespace defined at the top of the XAML? If it is, it must not be the one where you defined the converter. Either move the converter to that namespace, or add a new `xmlns:something` for the converter and use that where you create the converter in the resources.

Comment: If it's not there, add it.

Comment: @AyushSoni Could I ask you a favor? I can't test UWP. I just got to the office and made a change to my answer to so it'll default to a transparent brush if the selected brush is `null`, as I was originally trying to do with `Brushes.Transparent`. If you could try the converter the way it is now and let me know if it works, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: there is some issue, this isn't working for me. Even the solution before this is not working correctly. I am trying to figure out if that's to do with my code. Will post when I find out.

Comment: @AyushSoni Is that with my last update, or the code as it was when you accepted it as an answer? Post the current code, we'll figure it out.

Comment: With the one I marked as answer. :(
I reset back to what it was. So I don't have the edited code. Problem:


`1` I select some children ListBox items in parent A


`2` I select parent B on parent, and select child there.
When I come back to A, it only shows the last item I selected in parent A's child listbox. 

I'd like to convert it to ViewModel completely as you said. Can you help with that?